# datetime in 'changes' and 'info'

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I've been using P4Python for getting changelist from Perforce. Since I need the submitted changes of last 5 minutes, I'm getting time from the server itself & reducing 5 minutes from it. This is what I used:

```
info = p4.run("info")
```

This returns datetime in format `2015/12/22 22:34:27 -0800 Pacific Standard Time`. However, when I run,

```
getChanges = p4.run("changes","-s","submitted", "-m 5","-l","//path/to/destination/...")
```

I get time in Epoch. Now I know that we can change that Epoch to PST(haven't figured that right now), but is there a way that I can get the datetime in the same format as `info` command?

P.S- I did check [P4 changes options](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html) but couldn't anything that would help me.